# One meal a day - meal planning

Tags: time-of-day, fad-diet, carbohydrates, ketosis, nutrition

I've recently come across the one meal a day (OMAD) diet where you essentially fast until a set time and then consume your days calories in a single meal. I know there are already questions related to this (e.g. [Is eating a meal with 2000 Calories at once any different from eating 4 times at 500 Calories?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3585/is-eating-a-meal-with-2000-calories-at-once-any-different-from-eating-4-times-at/4010#4010)) and I'm not here to debate whether OMAD is a worthwhile diet or not.

Rather, I'd like to get some input on what the makeup of that single meal should be. I've seen many people suggest the OMAD diet without recommending any specific meal plan/breakdown

I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKfR6bAXr-c) discussing how/why OMAD works. If I understand this correctly, by only eating a single meal glucose/insulin levels in your body are allowed to drop, and ketosis is allowed to start providing more stable energy release throughout the day and to use up energy stored in fat cells. Is that a correct understanding?

Given that, is it advisable to eat a carb heavy single meal? I would imagine that would cause glucose levels to spike - does that then get stored back into fat cells thus preventing weight loss?

In general, what is a recommended breakdown for the contents of that single meal?

Answer (score 1):

Individual Results Vary

- Some people only eat food 30 points or lower on the Insulin Index.  Low carb, medium protein, high fat.  This is usually where the ketosis plays in, but is usually only necessary for people with a high carb addiction, and they should [taper down very slowly](http://livinlavidalowcarb.com/blog/is-ketosis-necessary-on-a-low-carb-diet-lets-ask-the-experts/2264).
- Other people are vegan and might do the above or the below.
- While others need high carbs for some reason.

It is usually wise to talk with your doctor or a nutritionist before changing anything radically.